# Connecting to more than one instance of DB2 from a PHP app on BlueMix

Tags: php, db2, ibm-cloud

how to use this code that connects to the db2 db....

//parse VCAP_SERVICES Environment variable

```
$vcap_services = $_ENV["VCAP_SERVICES"];
$services_json = json_decode($vcap_services,true);
$sqldb = $services_json["sqldb"];
if (empty($sqldb)) {
    echo "No sqldb service instance is bound. Please bind a sqldb service instance";
    return;
}

//Get Credentials object (db,host,port,username,password)
$sqldb_config = $services_json["sqldb"][0]["credentials"];

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=".
   $sqldb_config["db"].
   ";HOSTNAME=".
   $sqldb_config["host"].
   ";PORT=".
   $sqldb_config["port"].
   ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=".
   $sqldb_config["username"].
   ";PWD=".
   $sqldb_config["password"].
   ";";


$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', ''); //db connection
```

...to connect to more than 1 db ... NOT at the same time of course.

OR ... if it is possible... can I have more than one schema?

basically... I'm gonna have client data in there ... and each client is going to have same tables with same names... and similar data structure.so I need to keep them seperate... in different databases or diferent schemas. But the code that I got connects automatically to my instance of db2 ... how do I tell that code which instance to connect to... IF I have more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s say that you have many SQL Database service instances bound to your application. Now if you run:

`$services_json["sqldb"]`

it will return an array containing an element for each SQL DB instance. To point to a specific instance you could do:

`$sqldb_config = $services_json["sqldb”][i]`

where *i* is the index of the service you want. I suggest you to take a look at the value of the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable within you application dashboard on Bluemix. There you’ll see the list of all the SQLDB service instances that are bound to your application.